# Updating the intermediary table Best practice PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, time-complexity

Lets Say I have Many to many relationship between the two tables students and subjects. So we create an intermediary table for mapping the data. Lets say it is students_subjects. The students_subjects table has 2 columns that is student_id & subject_id.

```
+------------+--------------+
| student_id | student_name |
+------------+--------------+
|            |              |
+------------+--------------+

+------------+--------------+
| subject_id | subject_name |
+------------+--------------+
|            |              |
+------------+--------------+

+------------+------------+
| student_id | subject_id |
+------------+------------+
|            |            |
+------------+------------+
```

Until a recent time when there is a update in students_subjects (student selecting subjects) what I did was delete all the subjects that student had an insert the new ones.

```
+------------+------------+----------+
| student_id | subject_id | selected |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 1          | 2          | 1        |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 1          | 2          | 0        |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

But recently I added a new column to this intermediary table as selected. So if a student selected new subjects and deselect some old subjects I add active for new ones and non_active for deselect ones. (I do this in PHP by getting the newly selected subjects and previously had subjects. Then compare both. When a student select subjects I check all the subjects that student has [active and non active]. If the newly selected subjects has previously non active subjects I active them and add the new ones. )

What is the best practice for doing this. I there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: This is not an answer. A kind of recommendation. You can use an ORM to figure out this type of relationships easier.

Comment: I'm no DBA, but maybe have two "effective date" columns? One with "effective start" and one with "effective end" (which may or may not be filled when the row is created). So, a class is "active" if it's after the start and before the end?

Comment: With the new "selected" column, do you query the table for the student id and fine id that are "1" and add those subjects to students and subjects table? Then set the "1" flag in the student_subjects table to "0"?

Comment: When a student select subjects I check all the subjects that student has (active and non active). If the newly selected subjects has previously non active subjects I active them and add the new ones.

Comment: do you want to track if a student enrolled for a subject in the past?

Comment: I don't want. But I keep them because I don't want to add a new record if they select a previous one.

Comment: Perhaps a combination of unique composite index and mysql upsert is suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think your first approach (deleting all associated rows and inserting new entries) is much more simpler.

If still want to have the `selected` field, a simple way would be to create unique composite index and using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. This can also prevent accidental insert of the same `user_id` and `subject_id` pair. First create the index:

```
ALTER TABLE `students_subjects` ADD UNIQUE `unique_student_subject`(`student_id`, `subject_id`);
```

Then, simply update the `selected` field for the student to `0` and insert the subjects the student selected. Example using `PDO`:

```
$studentId = 1;
$newlySelectedSubjects[] = ['subject_id' => 3];
$newlySelectedSubjects[] = ['subject_id' => 4];

$db = new PDO("connection string here", $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$db->beginTransaction();

try{
    $qry = 'UPDATE students_subjects SET selected = 0 WHERE student_id = :studentId';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($qry);
    $stmt->execute(['studentId' => $studentId]);

    $insertQry = 'INSERT INTO students_subjects (student_id, subject_id, selected)' 
                 .'VALUES (:studentId, :subjectId, 1) '
                 .'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '
                 .'selected = 1';
    $insertStmt = $db->prepare($insertQry);

    foreach ($newlySelectedSubjects as $subject) {

        $params = ['studentId' => $studentId, 'subjectId' => $subject['subject_id']];
        $insertStmt->execute($params);
    }
    $db->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //do something with exception
    $db->rollBack();
}
```

What will happen is, if the student with `student_id` = `1` and `subject_id` = `3` already exist in the table, the `selected` field will be set to `1`, if not a new record will be inserted.

If you require to track the user subjects selection and the de-selection, I suggest implementing some sort of audit trails and leave the `students_subjects` to only hold the relationship between students and subjects. It can be easier with the help of mysql `TRIGGER`.A simplified example of an audit trail table:

```
+------------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| student_id | subject_id | action   | action_datetime     |
+------------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| 1          | 2          | remove   | 2018-01-01 00:01:23 |
+------------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| 1          | 4          | add      | 2018-01-01 01:07:45 |
+------------+------------+----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: I think this approach is great.